# Check checkboxes whose ids in a php array using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I am doing an edit functionality for a form that contains `checkboxes`. i.e I submit data from this form then upon submit there's a provision to edit the previously submitted data.

I have an array containing the submitted checkbox values. So I want for each of the checkboxes whose values are contained in the `php array`, I want to have them checked using `jQuery`.

I have tried below:

HTML:

```
<?php
foreach ($selections as $selection) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $selection -> Name . "</td><td><input type=checkbox id=" . $selection -> Name . " name=selections[] value=" . $selection -> id . " /></td></tr>";
}?>
```

SCRIPT:

```
var checkboxarray = <?php echo json_encode($checkboxarray) ?>;

        $.each(checkboxarray, function (i, elem){

        if(elem.name == $('input[name ="selections[]"]').attr('id')){

            $('input[name ="selections[]"]').attr('checked','checked');

            }

        })
```

However , it does not seem to function correctly.

Help appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: how does your `$checkboxarray` look like?

Comment: `$('input[name ="selections[]"]')` selects all the checkboxes, not some particular one. Try simply `$('#' + elem.name).attr('checked', 'checked')` instead.

Comment: Thank you `$('#' + elem.name).attr('checked', 'checked')` is more specific and it works better.

Comment: @MihaiIorga `vardump($checkboxarray)` returns something like: `array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$.each(checkboxarray, function (i, elem){
    if($('#'+elem.name) != 'undefined'){
        $('#'+elem.name).attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the `id` attribute directly in your selector:

```
$.each(checkboxarray, function (){
        if($('#' + this.name).length){
            $('#' + this.name).attr('checked','checked');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can also

try

```
foreach ($selections as $selection) {
    $checked    =   in_array($selection -> Name, $checkboxarray ) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
echo "<tr><td>" . $selection -> Name . "</td><td><input type=checkbox id=" . $selection -> Name . " name=selections[] value=" . $selection -> id . " ".$checked."/></td></tr>";
}
```

here `$checkboxarray` is your array list of checked

Comment: true no need for `jQuery` . I found it easier however to use it, as array seemed somewhat multidimensional such that I would have required nested `for loop` s  for  `in_array` to work.